# Why my session scoped managed bean is not retaining value of property?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a session scoped managed bean with the propety:

```
private EscalaMensalStruct escalaOrigem;
```

which I set manually in a method, let say, setEscalaOrigem(EscalaMensalStruct ems), but when I call the method

```
 public void sugerirDobra()
    {
        for (final EscalaMensalStruct escalaDiaria : Cache.getInstance().getListaEscalaDiaria())
        {
            if (escalaDiaria.getLinha().equals(this.escalaOrigem.getLinha()))
            {
                if (escalaDiaria.getFim() <= escalaDiaria.getInicio())
                {
                    this.listaDobra.add(escalaDiaria);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

escalaOrigin is null. The bean was viewScoped and I changed to sessionScoped thinking that would solve the problem, but it continues to trow nullPointerException in the first if.
I'm 100% sure that the setEscalaOrigin method is not receiving null, I dont know what else could be.

***Edit:***
The following code was in the button which calld sugerirDobra and it was setting escalaOrigem to null. Thats what you get for changing the attribute's name without changing the setter name.

```
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{null}"
    target="#{escalaDiariaTrocaController.escalaParaTrocaOrigem}">
</f:setPropertyActionListener>
```

Comment: That's something impossible to know with the given code... Just search for the `escalaOrigem` assignations and check `null` is not being assigned. Also check the bean itself is not being rebuilt..

Comment: How would I check the bean is not being rebuilt?

Comment: Just a breakpoint in its constructor.

Comment: If you have escalaOrigem == null another managed bean instance was created. Debug the code placing break point in the setEscalaOrigem(EscalaMensalStruct ems), take note of the id for the "this" variable, place the second break point in the method sugerirDobra and check the this id is the same as the previous one. If you confirm that (the ids are different) you need to revise your CDI structure. If the id is the same, you are calling sugerirDobra before setEscalaOrigem.

Comment: Edited the question to show my beginner's mistake.